# Different JSON pages

Tags: javascript, json, html5-canvas, appframework

i have 2 web pages containing same JSON string. one work fine with java-script function.but other one is completely not working.the only different between these two is url.

here is the page that is working fine with the js function.

```
 (http://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/?test=some+html+content&callback=?)
```

here is the one that is not working with the js function.

```
 (http://sanjeewa88.byethost31.com/EMPStore/test_json.html)
```

here is my java-script function

```
function doJSON() {
 $.getJSON('http://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/?test=some+html+content&callback=?', function (data) {

           $('#allemployees').append("<li>" + data.test+ "</li>");

                   });
                    }
```

what's wrong with second page and how i fix it to access that page through js function.

PS-
i want to display these data in a listview. first one is displaying that remote data on  the listview.but second one which having same json string is not displaying anything.

Comment: "Not working" is never useful.  What are the expected results and what result do you get?

Comment: i want to display these data in a listview. first one is displaying that remote data on the listview.but second one which having same json string is not displaying anything on the list view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the page you provide the json you have to accept a para callback and use this parameter to generate the function name.
look what's happen when you call jsfiddle callback with an other name:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/?test=some+html+content&callback=poney
```

give:

```
poney({"test": "some html content"});
```

You have more information here: [jQueryDoc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead. See the discussion of the jsonp data type in $.ajax() for more details.

Comment: first url is returning json string successfully.but the second one is not working.

Comment: because when the first one is called it have is parameter callback setted to a function name that jQuery will call after the page load. Your second url do not use this callback parameter so it's will not work. You have to check for a callback parameter and replace the ? by a the function name give in callback parameter

Comment: can you please give me little help to figure out.here is my second url.  http://sanjeewa88.byethost31.com/EMPStore/test_json.html  what are the positions that i need to change or add..

Comment: You can't do it with a static page. you have to use a php/ruby/python or any language to provide the page so you will be able to get the callback attribute and give it back around your json. Why do you need to do jsonp ? you really need your data, from json, to be on other server? if it's not the case do not call the full url (just EMPStore/test_json.html) and remove the ?() part and put only the real json